# JS API Fetch database items based on values of their certain parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have a database that looks something like this:

```
[{"id":1,"type":"a"},
 {"id":2,"type":"b"},
 {"id":3,"type":"c"},
 {"id":4,"type":"a"}]
```

What I need is to use fetch to get only the database items whose type parameter has a certain value (for example fetching type='a' should get items with IDs 1 and 4). So far I have only such get function:

```
get() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(`url`,) 
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => resolve(json))
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err);
    });
});
```

and cannot figure out how to filter the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front end solution : filter your json result in the front :  (This isn't a good idea if your database has a lot of items, since you still get all of them by http and then filter them in your browser which is extra work for the server and browser)

```
get(type) {
    return fetch('url')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => json.filter(item => item.type == type))
      //.catch(err => doSomethingWithErr(err)) 
      //you can handle error here or when you use get
}
```

Back end solution : add a query string to your url and handle it in the backend to only get the said type from the database.
Can't help you with code on this one since we don't know about your backend stack.

Comment: Well, that was simple. Works fine, thank you very much"

Comment: There's no need to create a new promise. You can just return the `fetch` and return `json.filter(item => item.type == type)` from the second `then`.

Comment: @Tholle indeed returning the fetch does the same thing. I just copied the code OP posted and modified it quickly, I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

> The Fetch API provides a JavaScript interface for accessing and manipulating parts of the HTTP pipeline, such as requests and responses. It also provides a global fetch() method that provides an easy, logical way to fetch resources asynchronously across the network.

Fetch API just helps you to deal with AJAX calls, and now it is up to you(client) to do perform some operations on the response, and convert it to the data you want.

**Fetch API can not help you with filter operation.**

You have 2 choices now:

1. Let Server do job of filtering -> You will need to pass some params to AJAX Call.
2. Use [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter your response data.Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580692/4192840) to do that.